# Coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, function found on Django form

Tags: python, django, forms, unicode

I'm new on Django and I'm making a formwhen I press submit I'm getting this error that I haven't seen before: `TypeError at /catalog/ coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, function found`

My `forms.py` looks like:

```
class AppsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        policiesList = kwargs.pop('policiesList', None)
        applicationList = kwargs.pop('applicationList', None)
        super(AppsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if policiesList and applicationList:
            self.fields['appsPolicyId'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Application Policy', choices=policiesList)
            self.fields['appsId'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Application', choices=applicationList)
        else:
            self.fields['appsPolicyId'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Application Policy',
                                                                  choices=('No application policies found',
                                                                           'No application policies found'))
            self.fields['appsId'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Application', choices=('No applications found',
                                                                    'No applications found'))
```

My `views.py` looks like:

```
def main(request):
    if validateToken(request):
        appList = getDetailsApplications(request)
        polList = getDetailsApplicationPolicies(request)
        message = None
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'deployButton' in request.POST:
            form = AppsForm(request.POST, policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
            if form.is_valid():
                deploy(request, form)
            else:
                form = AppsForm(policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
                message = 'Form not valid, please try again.'
        elif request.method == 'POST' and 'undeployButton' in request.POST:
            form = AppsForm(request.POST, policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
            if form.is_valid():
                undeploy(request, form)
            else:
                form = AppsForm(policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
                message = 'Form not valid, please try again.'
        else:
            form = AppsForm(policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
        return render_to_response('catalog/catalog.html', {'message': message, 'form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('menu/access_error.html')
```

The error happens on `deploy(request, form)` and `undeploy(request, form)`, they are on another app and I import both from the `app/views.py`.

Here I show one of them because I think the problem on both it's the same, but I'm not unable to fix it...

```
def deploy(request, form):
    if validateToken(request):
        policy = form.cleaned_data['appsPolicyId']
        applicationID = form.cleaned_data['appsId']
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        deployApp = apacheStratosAPI + applications + '/' + applicationID + '/' + deploy + '/' + policy
        req = requests.post(deployApp, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(request.session['stratosUser'],
                                                                      request.session['stratosPass']),
                       verify=False)
        if req.status_code == 202:
            serverInfo = json.loads(req.content)
            message = '(Code: ' + str(req.status_code) + ') ' + serverInfo['message'] + '.'
            return render_to_response('catalog/catalog.html', {'message': message, 'form': form},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        elif req.status_code == 400 or req.status_code == 409 or req.status_code == 500:
            serverInfo = json.loads(req.content)
            message = '(Error: ' + str(req.status_code) + ') ' + serverInfo['message'] + '.'
        return render_to_response('catalog/catalog.html', {'message': message, 'form': form},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('menu/access_error.html')
```

The error it's on the line:

```
deployApp = apacheStratosAPI + applications + '/' + applicationID + '/' + deploy + '/' + policy
```

When I debug, I see that the variables are correct and on format `u'value'`. I don't know why now I'm getting the Unicode error because on other forms that I have the values are on this format and I don't get any error.

Why I get this error now? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things you're including in that string concatenation is `deploy`. Since that isn't defined within the current scope, Python will look for the nearest declaration of that name, which is the current function itself, hence the error.

I don't know where that name is actually supposed to be defined, but you should probably do it within your function; and, in any case, you will need to rename either the variable or the function.

Comment: Your comment opened my eyes! The `deploy` variable was defined on the top level of `app/views.py` and then I changed the name of the function to `deploy` and forgot to rename the variable. I forgot that Python couldn't differentiate between them. What  stupid mistake. Thanks!